# Responsive background image by cropping

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I know that smaller screen don't need the large 2000px wide .jpg stock image of a beautiful carribean sunset. Concrete: My Nokia phone and my bandwidth dictate the limits of a great user experience. It's about the loading time.

Some folks want to offer smaller screen sizes a different, smaller image.
They want to offer a *different* ressource (E.g. per `<picture>` element) and I don't want this because I know it's only the one image that I want to serve the user.

I want one `<img>` and I want that the browsers download as much of the file as they need to display it optimal. I want to art-direct the cropping and scaling via stylesheet.

Should we encourage that browsers download and display image ressource as they need or should I do browser sniffing and duplicate and crop my images in photoshop — because this works today?

Comment: using @media queries combined with 'background' is the only browser-side solution i can think of. See DavidTaiaroa answer.

Comment: Yeah but that's a hack. It's a real photographic image (Including meta information useful for software like search engines) and not a decorative background-image.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specifics of what you want to achieve, here's one possiblitly that might work for you.

You start by using media queries to deliver different background images @ different viewports:

```
CSS  
body{
background-image:url('desktop.jpg');
}  

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
body{
background-image:url('tablet.jpg');
}  
}  

@media (max-width: 768px) {
body{
background-image:url('smartphone.jpg');
}    
}
```

Then you fine-tune the results by using full page background image techniques, eg
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that approach. I know it does work but it's redundand and not easy to maintain. I guess I have to wait 'til the browser vendors implement an intelligent solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not very feasible with the current browser technology.

In theory, you could sniff screen dimensions with JavaScript, set the background image URL with width and height information available and then crop the image on the server side to match these dimensions.

But

- This would be utterly complex
- It fails if the user resizes the browser window
- If fails if user rotates a mobile device
- Non-cache friendly
- etc.

My suggestion is to use responsive CSS layout. http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-backgrounds/